# preupdate event doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have this code but I have a problem to insert object `$modificacion` in database.

```
class ListenerCrud{

    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs){

        if ($eventArgs->getEntity() instanceof Usuario) {

            $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
            $modificacion = new Modificacion();
            $modificacion->setFechamod(new \DateTime('now'));
            $modificacion->setEntidad('Usuario');
            $modificacion->setTipo('uupdate');
            $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
            $modificacion->setEmpleado($securityContext->getToken()->getUser());
            $modificacion->setInfo('hi');
            $em->persist($modificacion);
            $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($modificacion));
            $em->getUnitOfWork()->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $modificacion);
        }
    }
}
```

In the `config.yml`, I have:

```
listenercrud:
    class: mio\mioBundle\ListenerCrud
    arguments: [@service_container]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: PreUpdate}
```

Answer (score 1):

The event name, in your YAML file, should be "preUpdate", not "PreUpdate".

```
listenercrud:
    class: mio\mioBundle\ListenerCrud
    arguments: [@service_container]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```